# How to make it so my form stays under my header unless I need to scroll?

Tags: html, css

So I guess the main question here is can I keep everything under my header nav bar that's in a fixed position but if I need to scroll it goes under my header? Here is a fiddle of me just setting the margin-top of the hr tag but after trying it on different screen sizes it just doesn't work and over laps on smaller screens.

https://jsfiddle.net/RVKuzmik/se0etqew/3/

```
Code here
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: 1;
}


hr {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Campus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<hr>
```

Comment: why you use `hr` this is not right way,

Comment: you can use border-bottom in header instead of hr

Comment: use the px instated of %

Answer (score 0):

```
**CSS**

html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

header {
    top:0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 1;
    height:80px;
}


**HTML**


<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<hr>
```

Comment: @InfiSnyp please check with the css remove Hr tage

Comment: you can add some snippet(fiddle) and highlight what exactly InfiSnyp is missing.

Answer (score 0):

try to add position fixed to your form this will work

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a percentage value as the `margin-top` on the `hr` element. The thing with percentage values is that it changes as the viewport changes, so on a smaller device the `10%` value may not be the same as it is on a large computer screen.

Since your navbar is going to stay the same height (with fixed elements on top it is always a good idea to know beforehand what's the maximum height the element will be at any given point).

Instead of giving `hr` tag a `margin-top` value, I would suggest you setting a `margin/padding-top` value on the top container of the elements that are in a scroll-able view and not fixed.

By default it will be the `body` element where your elements positioned normally and the fixed header / navbar is, so let's do it on it.

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}

body {

  /* The height of the header is around 70px (give or take) at most of the screens, since you are using percentage value for the padding-top and bottom of it  */
  margin-top: 70px;

}

header {
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/00w0cng6/

Or even better, to make sure things look right on every device, you either use responsive media queries to set different values for certain screen sizes or just one fixed height for your fixed element.

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  /* 70px because that's the max our fixed element is going to be */
  margin-top: 70px;
}

header {
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;

  /* Padding top, bottom and the height of the header sums up to 70px */
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;

  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RVKuzmik/se0etqew/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just give the header a `background:color:white;position:sticky` And it will work fine..
What is happening is that the header has a background color which is transparent and position is fixed....This will work fine..

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of position: fixed

for example:
[Here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc2Oa.png)

Comment: Then it should work. Try adding some content to your page and then check it out

Comment: I know it is work but before you post answer Please check code, Thanks!